# 'TimeseriesGenerator' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

I have a LSTM model. which when I try to fit i get the error mentioned in the title.

I have an array of timeseries data with multiple features I'm feeding as input. The code that is causing the error is below.

```
TimeseriesGenerator(features, target, length=100, sampling_rate=1, batch_size=100)[0]

train_generator = TimeseriesGenerator(x_train,y_train,length=win_length,sampling_rate=1,batch_size=batch_size)


early_stopping=tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                                                patience=2,
                                                mode='min')
model.compile(loss=tf.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
             optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(),
             metrics=[tf.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()])

history=model.fit_generator(train_generator,epochs=50,
                           validation_data=test_generator,
                           shuffle=False,
                           callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

I've been losing my mind over this all day and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: But you forgot to show the most important part of your question: the `train_generator`

Comment: @AloneTogether oops - i've added the train_generator as well as the timeseriesgenerator code above. thanks!

Comment: It seems model.fit_generator expects the first parameter to be something that has the parameter shape and this is not the case for the parameter train_generator that you used. Give a look at the docs of model.fit_generator  to see exactly what it expects as first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I have two changes for you and the code will work fine.

TimeseriesGenerator() and Sequential() model must be from the same library - either from Keras or from tensorflow.
So the solution is as follows

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
```